# Как правильно писать обозначение населенного пункта?

Tags: склонение, ономастика

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно писать обозначение населенного пункта  - микрорайон Ложок. Склоняется ли оно? Как варианты, без обозначения микрорайона, люди говорят - в Ложках, в Ложке.

Comment: @ПИрсен, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Если топоним заканчивается на твердый согласный, то он склоняется (II склонение): Ложок - Ложка - в Ложке.

2) При наличии приложения несклоняемость таких топонимов обычно характерна для профессиональной речи (в микрорайоне Ложок), где требуется особая точность наименования.

3)В разговорной речи такое словосочетание лучше не употреблять, оно стилистически неточно. Но вот в сочетании "в городе Ложке" топоним склоняется.

Answer (score 1):

"Ложок" - это, видимо, "лог", только маленький. Тогда - слово "ложок" склоняется по II склонению.
В словосочетании "микрорайон Ложок" склоняется слово "микрорайон". Слово "ложок" - не меняется.